# Export dataframe to excel

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a df with these fields:

customer_name, group_id, group_name, income, market_share

I would like to create a table in excel in a way I can expand/collapse the cells on group_name.

So it would look something like this:

```
group_name| 
          |customer_name| income| market_share|
          |customer_name| income| market_share|
group_name|             |       |             |
          |customer_name| income| market_share|
          |customer_name| income| market_share|
          |customer_name| income| market_share|
group_name|             |       |             |
          |customer_name| income| market_share|
```

Comment: I was thinking if converting the df to a dictionary would be easier by setting the key as the group_name

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas get datafram and use numpy for create pivot table by code below;

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data= pd.read_table("your data")#,aggfunc=np.mean)
np.round(pd.pivot_table(data, values='value, index= 'group_name','customer_name','income','market_share'], aggfunc=np.mean))